# angular 9 web worker IE

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, web-worker

Angular 9. I create the worker in this way as below and it works everywhere without problems, except IE. As far as I understand, there is a problem in the `type: 'module'`, but without it I get 404 not found.

`public myWorker = new Worker('./{path}/my.worker', { type: 'module' });`

how can I get this to work for all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in IE 11 because [IE doesn't support `options.type` parameter in web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker#browser_compatibility). But from the [Angular doc](https://v9.angular.io/guide/web-worker), it seems that we must use `type: 'module'` when adding a web worker in Angular.

As [IE is going to retire next year](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/05/19/the-future-of-internet-explorer-on-windows-10-is-in-microsoft-edge/), I suggest that you can stop support your app in IE. Otherwise, I think you can only use other solutions to achieve what you want in IE without web worker.

Comment: I would happy to stop supporting IE, but... this is required by the specifics of the project. 
so I'm looking for possible solution

Comment: I searched a lot but didn't find other solutions. I only find [a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59975523/angular-8-web-workers-are-broken-in-ie), you can refer to it. Let's wait to see if other community members have other suggestions.